# UIImageView tintColor not changing using storyboard

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, storyboard

I have the rendering more of the image in AssetCatalog as Template :

[image]

I have then changed the tintColor for UIImageView which is using this image :

[image]

**But when I run the app**, the color of image is still black.
After going through one of the links I found that I need to add a user defined attribute for UIImageView. So I added that as well, but it is still showing black on running the app.

[image]

**Note : I want to achieve this from Storyboard ONLY.**

Comment: Is your imageView is a custom view?

Comment: @QuocNguyen: Just a regular UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by changing the global tint color and the tint color. both are affecting what you need to do.
i think it is an xcode bug but it works like that.
other wise you can do that using a line of code:

```
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

[image: Global tint color]